# Copying (and deleting) rows in Google Sheets based on dropdown (Data sourced from Google Survey)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a newbie when it comes to any sort of coding, but I'm trying to figure out a way to fix my spreadsheet. I am working on a Google Sheet for a trucking company where data comes in via a Google Form (e.g. date, driver, amount, pickup, destinaiton, etc) and is a linked to a spreadsheet with responses recorded to a sheet called "Loadboard". Responses start on Row 5.

On "Loadboard", I created a dropdown column called "Paid" in Column R (18) as a place to mark when these orders are completed. The idea is that once "Yes" is selected it will be moved from the "Loadboard" sheet to the "Paid" sheet. I also created a "No" option as part of the dropdown in case we need to move from "Paid" back to "Loadboard" in case this dropdown is selected accidentally.

While I have an onedit function that works great, I'm having trouble figuring out how to convert this to work with data submitted via form (in particular how to write the new onformsubmit function and how to setup the form submission trigger)

Here's the function I'm using:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  let r = e.range;
  if (r.columnStart != 18 || r.rowStart == 1 || e.value == null) return;
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const valArray = ["No", "Yes"];
  const destArray = ["Loadboard", "Paid"];
  let dest = sh.getSheetByName(destArray[valArray.indexOf(e.value)]);
  let src = sh.getActiveSheet();
  if (dest.getName() == src.getName()) return;
  src.getRange(r.rowStart, 1, 1, 18).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 18));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
}
```

After searching for hours on the internet, this was the closest I got -

```js
function formSubmission() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var numCol = range.getLastColumn();
  var row = s.getActiveRow;
  var targetinfo = s.getRange(row, (18).getValue);
  if (targetinfo() == "Yes") {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Paid");
    var targetrow = targetSheet.getLastrow() + 1);
    var Targetcol = numCol();
    targetSheet.getRange(targetrow, 1, 1, Targetcol).setValues(data);
  }
}
```

I'm also using the following trigger setup:

- **Function to Run:** OnEdit
- **Event Source:** From Spreadsheet
- **Event Type:** On Change

Unfortunately, neither seem to be working. I also just tried replacing the original onedit with "formsubmission" which did not work.

Comment: on form submit event can be applied with an installable trigger.
About installable trigger: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: but instead of keep editing the data and moving them around the sheets, I would rather keep the data untouched, and use ```Query()``` to retrieve the data I need. Let's say your data has these headings: ```{date, driver, amount, paid}```, put a function like ```=QUERY({'data sheet'!A1:D},"WHERE Col4='Yes'",1)```, this will show only the data with a ```Yes``` in the ```paid``` column, which is like 1000 time easier then moving the data around.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to do the same thing, I would let a sheet with all the results untouched. I would make a namedRange with it and two sheets Paid and Loadboard with a request like =QUERY(myNamedRange, "select * where R='Yes'") so get a clean sheet with every "Paid" row.

About your code, a hint : I can't find any var row s.getActiveRow function and i it existed it would be s.getActiveRow() (parenthesis).

Comment: This method doesn't work for me. This survey that this info is pulled from is active and I need to be able to move the information to "paid" because this information moves into an invoice template automatically unless it's on the paid tab. There's another "driver report" tab that this information pulls from. Is there anyway to create a macro that can just move (and delete) the rows of information pulled from google form?